# Browser Locale in Playframework

Tags: playframework, timezone, locale

How do i get the locale of the browser making a request using Play Framework?
I am looking for something like HttpServletRequest.getLocale().

I specifically need to get hold of timezone of the browser making the request.

Appreciate any help in this regards.

Answer (score 2):

Check `play.i18n.Lang.getLocale()`

Comment: I believe this returns the locale of the server and not the request.

Comment: yup, sure enough it is reading from the request and if there is trouble, then it reads from server.

Comment: hmmm, I don't see timezone in the Local object, just languages?

Comment: This property is not available in Play 2.0 any updates on how to get the browser's locale or timezone?

Comment: probably a far from nice solution to get the locale is to store a string `my.locale=en-US` etc. in the messages files and retrieve it via `Messages.get()` but a timezone … no clue.